# How to resolve null json string passed to mvc controller?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I created a table using a list of model objects.
Then passed the row data to an Ajax post when a button on that row is clicked.

Within the Ajax Post `.stringify` is called on that row data passed down.
When I check the values of the data passed on the wire in Dev Tools I can see that they are populated:

```
["66", "jdoe@gmail.com", "2009", "test",…]
0
:
"66"
1
:
"jdoe@gmail.com"
2
:
"2009"
3
:
"test"
```

But when I step into the controller POST action that is called from client side. The expected JSON string is **null / empty.** My thoughts are that maybe this is beacause stringify has no property names to associate with each value in the array.

**Question:**

How can you resolve null json string passed to mvc controller?

Here is a gist of the implementation below -

Model:

```
public class Status
{

        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }


        public string Contact_Email { get; set; }

        public string RID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }



    }
```

Table and AJAX post method:

```
     <table id="statusTable" class="table table-hover table-bordered results">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>RID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Update Record</th>


                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach (var row in Model.ReleaseStatus)
            {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.Raw(row.ID)</td>
                        <td>@Html.Raw(row.Contact_Email_Name)</td>
                        <td>@row.RID</td>
                        <td>@row.Name</td>
                        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button></td>
                    </tr>
              }
            </tbody>

        </table>



 $(".btn-success").click(function () {
            var $td = $(this).closest('tr').children("td"),
            len = $td.length;
            var tableData = $td.map(function (i) {
                if (i < len - 1)
                    return $(this).text();
            }).get();

            console.log(tableData);

            //Post JSON data to controller
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'updateStatus',
                data: JSON.stringify(tableData),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log("post success");
                },
                error: function (request) {
                    console.log("post error" + request.error);
                }

            });


        });
```

And finally the POST method in the MVC controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult updateStatus(stirng jsonString)
    {
        //deserialise the json to a Status object here
    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to bind to a `string` instead of your model. Your method should be `public ActionResult updateStatus(Status model)` and the data `var data = { ID: 66, Contact_Email: 'jdoe@gmail.com', etc }`

Comment: I did try specifying a onject in the mvc action, like updateStatus(Status vm) the object is null during the post. I think the main issue is that my data being passed down in jquery has no name attached to the values?

Comment: Yes, that why you need generate and object (as per my previous comment) and in the ajax remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` and use `data: data,`

Comment: But your not editing any properties of your model, so what is the point of this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your controller needs to be created to accept the actual object, and not the json string.

By this i mean

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult updateStatus(stirng jsonString)
{
   //deserialise the json to a Status object here
}
```

Should be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult updateStatus(Status vm)
{
   //no need to deserialize - was already done by the model binder
}
```

In order for the model binder to bind your json to `Status` you would need to pass a json object that replicates your viewmodel.

```
{
 ID:yourId, 
 Contact_Email:yourContactEmail, 
 RID:YourRID, 
 Name:yourName
}
```

In pseudo-code, you could:

```
var statusData = {
     ID:tableData[0], 
     Contact_Email:tableData[1],
     RID:tableData[2], 
     Name:tableData[3]
};
```

Then in your ajax call,

```
data: JSON.stringify(statusData),
```

Comment: Good answer however more explanation would make it even better

Comment: This wont do anything unless OP also generates the object in the view correctly instead of posting back an array

Comment: I tried passing in a Status object before the json string, and each value in the object is null when it reaches the action method. I think it is because my data doesn't specify the name if each value?

Comment: @BrianJ - I added a little more explanation to why you're getting nulls. This is what Stephen refers to in his comment on this answer.

Comment: Ok I think adding an attribute tag name on in the model for each property, would resolve the names of the json objects values? Like the `[DisplayName("ID")]
public int ID { get; set; }`

Comment: @BrianJ, All your posting currently is an array of values - it can b=never be serialized to anything other that `List<object>` (adding `[DisplayName]` will not do anything to solve the issue)

Comment: Added some more info for you @BrianJ

Comment: @StephenMuecke that makes more sense, I did notice that one of the rows I omitted in the question of type DateTime doesn't get mapped to the object. Although the date format seems correct "05/17/2016". For example all the rest of the properties map except for `Create_Date : tableData[5],` which is of type DateTime in my model. Any ideas why the mapping would fail there?

Comment: @BrianJ - do this for your date. `Create_Date: new Date(tableData[5])` - give it an actual date.

Comment: If you value is `05/17/2016` and the culture in your server is `MM/dd/yyy` then it will work fine (there is no need for `new Date()`).

Answer (score -2):

try the from body attribute

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult updateStatus([FromBody]Status status)
{
    //add the serialize attribute on your model 
}
```